# Dictionary comprehension with lambda functions gives wrong results

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I tried the following code in Python 3.5.1:

```
>>> f = {x: (lambda y: x) for x in range(10)}
>>> f[5](3)
9
```

It's obvious that this should return `5`. I don't understand where the other value comes from, and I wasn't able to find anything.

It seems like it's something related to reference - it always returns the answer of `f[9]`, which is the last function assigned.

What's the error here, and how should this be done so that it works properly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Python scoping is lexical**. A closure will refer to the name and scope of the variable, not the actual object/value of the variable.

What happens is that each lambda is capturing the variable `x` *not* the value of `x`.

At the end of the loop the variable `x` is bound to 9, therefore **every lambda will refer to this `x` whose value is 9.**

Why @ChrisP's answer works:

> `make_func` forces the value of `x` to be evaluated (as it is passed
>   into a function). Thus, the lambda is made with value of `x` currently
>   and we avoid the above scoping issue.

```
def make_func(x):
    return lambda y: x

f = {x: make_func(x) for x in range(10)}
```

Comment: An alternate shorthand would be `f = {x: (lambda y, x=x: x) for x in range(10)}`, because function default arguments are bound at definition time, so they'd bind the _value_ of `x`, not the _name_ `x`.

Comment: This may sound like a very dumb question (I'm not too familiar with lambda), but how does make_func(x) work? I can imagine that f[5](3) means -> f = {5:make_func(5)}. So how is it that make_func(5)(3) equal to 5?

Comment: The dictionary comprehension makes a dictionary keys of ints to values of functions. f[5] returns the value in the dictionary keyed by 5 which happens to be the function lambda y: x. Note the lambda ignores whatever is passed in (y) and always returns x. That is why the lambda will either return 5 or 9 (due to the issue described above).

Comment: @gnicholas I see, so basically lambda is relying on a global x value (i.e. global within the scope of the dictionary?)

Comment: The comment about "lexical scoping" seems confusing to me. Many other languages have lexical scoping (e.g., Haskell, Java), and do not suffer from this constraint. For example (Haskell):
`import Data.Map`; `let f = fromList [(x, \y -> x) | x <- [1..10]]`; `fmap ($ 3) (Data.Map.lookup 5 f)` results in `Just 5`. Could you clarify how you're using the term "lexical scope"?

Comment: Also see the `Lazy binding` paragraph in [Common Gotchas In Python](http://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python).

Comment: @ShadowRanger solution is nice!

Answer (score 9):

The following should work:

```
def make_func(x):
    return lambda y: x

f = {x: make_func(x) for x in range(10)}
```

The `x` in your code ends up referring to the last `x` value, which is `9`, but in mine it refers to the `x` in the function scope.